# How to use the choosen language to show an especifc pdf file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im a beginner with react.js and thats my question. I have a system that the user can choose the default language. So, if the language its french, i have an especific url to put in my Iframe path.If its spanish, an especific pdf. But how can I do the logic?

I have something like this:

```
function Iframe(props) {
    return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.iframe ? props.iframe : "" }} />);
}

//defalut pdf cause im not verifying the language yet. 
const iframe = '<iframe src="https://myPDFinFrench.pdf" width="1361" height="550"></iframe>';
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not use the language (wherever you have stored it) to choose from different PDF files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use templating to conditionally render the URL in the iframe, like this:

```
const language = 'FR';

const iframeFactory = {
  'ES': 'https://spanish.pdf/',
  'FR': 'https://french.pdf/',
}

function Iframe() {
    const iframe = `<iframe src=${iframeFactory[language]} width="1361" height="550"></iframe>`

    return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: iframe }} />);
}
```